# SQL Statement to display only the duplicate zip codes from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
Small Part of the Instructor Table
--------------------------------------------------
Instructor_ID Salutation First     Last     Street Address  Zip
101           Mr         Fernand   Hanks    100 East 87th   10015
102           Mr         Tom       Wojick   518 West 120th  10025
103           Ms         Nina      Schorin  210 West 101st  10025
104           Mr         Gary      Pertez   34 Sixth Ave    10035
105           Ms         Anita     Morris   34 Maiden Lane  10015
106           Rev        Todd      Smythe   210 West 101st  10025
107           Dr         Marilyn   Frantzen 254 Bleeker     10005
108           Mr         Charles   Lowry    518 West 120th  10025
109           Hon        Rick      Chow     56 10th Avenue  10015
110           Ms         Irene     Willig   415 West 101st  (null) 
------------------------------------------------------------------
Small Part of the Student Table

152     Mr.    Thomas       Edwards     501 W. Elm                      07036
157     Ms.    Shirley      Jameson     101 Daniel St.                  07008
158     Mr.    Roy          Limate      5 Horizon Rd.                   07024
159     Mr.    Thomas       Edwards     45 Maplewood Ave.               07040
160     Mr.    John T.      Beitler     100 Plaza Dr, ITT CSI Emp. Dpt  07096
168     Ms.    Sally        Naso        812 79th St.                    07047
182     Mr.    Jeffrey      Delbrun     PO Box 1091                     07024
185     Mr.    Dennis       Mehta       371 Monmouth St.                07302
186     Ms.    Christine    Sheppard    16 Seymour St.                  07042
187     Mr.    O.           Garnes      125 Great Hills Rd              07078
```

Write a set operation, using the UNION set operator, to list all the duplicate zip codes in the INSTRUCTOR and STUDENT tables.

Here is what I have come up with, not sure if its right or not.

```
select zip, count(*) from instructor
group by zip
having count(*) > 1
union
select zip, count(*) from student
group by zip
having count(*)>1
```

Please Help!!

```
OUTPUT:
Zip     Count(*)
06820   3
06830   3
06880   2
06903   2
07003   2
07010   6
07011   2
07012   2
07016   2
07024   9
```

Comment: 1) What is it? [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle]? 2) What is your input and what your expected output? 3) Does your query show desired output? If not, then you can be sure it's wrong.

Comment: If you arent sure, test it.

Comment: @PerlDog i get an output, but it shows me the zipcode and number beside it, which represents the number of times its duplicated. 
for example  

    06820      3
    06830      3
    06880      2

Comment: Please post your starting data and desired result.

Comment: Note that `union` removes duplicates in the result set. Use `union all`. I.e. if `instructor` table gives `06820/3` and `student` would also give `06820/3` then this would be shown only once with `union` (without `all`). The question is _“What exactly means ‘all the duplicate zip codes in the INSTRUCTOR and STUDENT tables’?”_ Your solution is not bad.

Comment: @Aleksej i updated the question, lemme know if its not enough, its just the database is verylong

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this question is getting down-voted and flamed so hard?  Honestly.  For a first question on SO, this is pretty good.  He/she showed good effort in their work, and only fell slightly short in describing their problem.

Comment: @PerlDog thank you man, apreciate it! :) it works a lot better now.

Comment: sorry guys i will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution basically does this:

- identify the dupes in INSTRUCTOR
- identify the dupes in STUDENT
- show them both (that's the UNION or UNION ALL)

I think you did that right.

But if I understand the question like follows, the statement would be different:

- Build the union of all ZIPs from both INSTRUCTOR and STUDENT
- *Now* identify the dupes

For example, exaclty one INSTRUCTOR has ZIP=99999 and exactly one STUDENT has ZIP=99999, then your solution would *not* show them as dupes.
With the latter understanding of the question this would very well *be* a dupe.

For the latter case the statement would/could be:

```
select x.zip from 
    (select zip from instructor
     union all
     select zip from student) x
group by x.zip
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thats an interesting approach, but you statement and mine, gave the same result, so i guess both of them are right.

Comment: Even better. So then instructors and students don't have a ZIP in common. You can verify by adding some student's ZIP to the instructor table. Then the results should differ.

Comment: +10. Mostly for asking the right kind of questions about the specification...  or was the spec to return zip codes that are duplicates within students AND are also duplicates within instructors... **`(dups in students) INTERSECT (dups in instructors)`** ? When we don't know, one of the first steps is to explain our interpretation of the spec. Examples are a good way to demonstrate possible "what if" scenarios, given this set of data, what should be the return. What if we remove this row, or update that row, or add a new row... what should be the return, etc.

Comment: Wow, @spencer7593 thank you. I really appreciate that. This question improved over the time as the OP added useful information when he was asked to do so and I actually liked that. So I thought it was worth thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct.  You can remove `count(*)` from your select, if you don't want to see that in the results.  The important part is your `GROUP BY ZIP HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

```
SELECT ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR
GROUP BY ZIP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
UNION
SELECT ZIP
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY ZIP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

As Perl Dog mentioned, you can also use `UNION ALL` if you want to see a ZIP twice in the results, if it is duplicated in both tables.  See his comment.

Comment: thanks @aaronD i apreciate your input. it helped out alot. also appreciate you defending my post.

Comment: When I'm doing a UNION ALL, I often include a discriminator column, usually string literal.  `SELECT 'instructors' AS src, i.zip, ...  UNION ALL SELECT 'students', s.zip, ... `. The spec didn't say anything about that, and it's probably beyond the scope of the question, but  quite often, I do care about which query returned a row. (I'm anticipating that the next question might be... which of these duplicate zips were from the instructor table, and which were from the student table?.)